# Web-connected scheduler BlackBerry Application

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to create an blackberry application that acts as a scheduler, which scheduled time can be updated via a website (not only from the app itself) as well. I am thinking of using a .txt file from a website that contains the String of the time, then let the app connects to the file every time it is started or refreshed. The app will also upload back the file to the web site every time a change is saved. Do you guys have any other ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the following:

[Blackberry Push Service](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/platform/pushapi.jsp)

OR

[Pusher | HTML5 WebSocket Powered Realtime Messaging Service](http://pusher.com/)